# Parsing issues bringing CSVs from Kaggle into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, kaggle

Edit: Figured this out and answered it below. This may be of help to other newbies in the future downloading csv files directly from kaggle. I did not realize even though the wget shows up as downloading csv files, they are actually zips.

I'm new to pandas and working with these datasets in general. I installed and upgraded to the latest version of kaggle-cli to download some kaggle datasets into my own VM to work with in Jupyter:

```
[root@sandbox ~]# kg dataset -u "me" -p "mypassword" -o "sohier" -d "london-police-records"
downloading https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/london-police-records/downloads/london-outcomes.csv

london-outcomes.csv 100% |##################################################################################| Time: 0:00:03  37.7 MiB/s

downloading https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/london-police-records/downloads/london-stop-and-search.csv

london-stop-and-search.csv 100% |###########################################################################| Time: 0:00:00   5.3 MiB/s

downloading https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/london-police-records/downloads/london-street.csv

london-street.csv 100% |####################################################################################| Time: 0:00:02  42.8 MiB/s
```

No issues with the download itself. When I try to use pandas to work with the data:

import pandas as pd

london_street = pd.read_csv('london-street.csv')

I get this:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ParserError                               Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-16-b1c1b3a6a38f> in <module>()
----> 1 london_street = pd.read_csv('london-street.csv')

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in parser_f(filepath_or_buffer, sep, delimiter, header, names, index_col, usecols, squeeze, prefix, mangle_dupe_cols, dtype, engine, converters, true_values, false_values, skipinitialspace, skiprows, nrows, na_values, keep_default_na, na_filter, verbose, skip_blank_lines, parse_dates, infer_datetime_format, keep_date_col, date_parser, dayfirst, iterator, chunksize, compression, thousands, decimal, lineterminator, quotechar, quoting, escapechar, comment, encoding, dialect, tupleize_cols, error_bad_lines, warn_bad_lines, skipfooter, skip_footer, doublequote, delim_whitespace, as_recarray, compact_ints, use_unsigned, low_memory, buffer_lines, memory_map, float_precision)
    653                     skip_blank_lines=skip_blank_lines)
    654 
--> 655         return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    656 
    657     parser_f.__name__ = name

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
    409 
    410     try:
--> 411         data = parser.read(nrows)
    412     finally:
    413         parser.close()

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1003                 raise ValueError('skipfooter not supported for iteration')
   1004 
-> 1005         ret = self._engine.read(nrows)
   1006 
   1007         if self.options.get('as_recarray'):

/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py in read(self, nrows)
   1746     def read(self, nrows=None):
   1747         try:
-> 1748             data = self._reader.read(nrows)
   1749         except StopIteration:
   1750             if self._first_chunk:

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.read (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:10862)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_low_memory (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11138)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._read_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11884)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._tokenize_rows (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:11755)()

pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx in pandas._libs.parsers.raise_parser_error (pandas/_libs/parsers.c:28765)()

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2
```

I've looked up the most similar problems I can find, and I've tried various options with the sep parameter and some other settings (which just breaks the parsing in different ways), but looking at this project itself and the data summary:

https://www.kaggle.com/sohier/london-police-records/data

It seems like it should be pretty straightforward. Does Kaggle munge external data downloads that I need to do something extra with before I can use it as a clean csv file?

Comment: my guess is that the csv file is just too large to fit in memory.  How big is the file?  Does `read_csv` give you an option of limiting the number lines it reads?  That would at least separate parsing format issues from memory ones.

Comment: @hpaulj I tried adding nrows=20 but the result is the same. There must be an issue with the formatting, based on the last line:

ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 3, saw 2

Comment: Now the error looks it has to do with the number of columns per line.  May be  the first line(s) are headers or comments, and should be skipped.

Comment: It loads fine for me. I did notice that the 4th line (or 3rd row of data) begins with a null entry. What version of pandas are you using? If it's an old one, pandas might be failing to recognize the null value (and thinks that your row has too few values).

Comment: Looks like 0.20.3. The VM is out-of-the-box for a class I'm in, I really don't know a ton about what's under the hood and installed in the OS, is this out of date?

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. The problem is that even though the download result on the wget referred to the file as .csv, it was actually a zip that was downloaded.

```
mv london-street.csv london-street.zip

unzip london-street.zip
```

There's the actual csv:

```
# ls
london-street.csv
london-street.zip
```

pulled it in with

```
london_street = pd.read_csv('london-street.csv')
london_street
```

And was able to see the data with no problem.